# what is the order of this function's execution: var queryResult = names.OrderBy(item => item).Where(it => it.StartsWith("S"))

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

what is the order of this function's execution:

```
var queryResult = names.OrderBy(item => item).Where(it => it.StartsWith("S"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `names` is a projection of a column from a simple table map, such as:

```
var names = ctx.SomeTable.Select(row => row.Name);
```

Well, that **by itself** doesn't actually do *any* execution; it builds a composed query representation that is (from the outside in):

1. `Where` [predicate]
2. (wrapping) `OrderBy` [selector]
3. (wrapping) `Select` [selector]
4. (wrapping) a table query

Nothing else happens until you either iterate the data (`foreach`, `GetEnumerator()`, etc) or call `First` (etc). With LINQ-to-SQL (from the tags) it then builds a single TSQL query (making the "order of execution" a problem only for the db engine itself) suitable for the current connection (the specific SQL-Server flavour), which will look something like:

```
SELECT row.Name
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] row
WHERE row.Name LIKE @p1
ORDER BY row.Name
```

probably passing `'S%'` as `@p1`.

If this were LINQ-to-Objects, data is *fetched* from the outside in, with each layer asking inner layers for data and filtering/manipulating it as necessary. As such, with LINQ-to-Objects it makes sense to do the `Where` ahead of the `OrderBy`. With LINQ-to-SQL it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `names` is. If you are using Linq-to-SQL then it will be compiled into one SQL query that ends:

```
WHERE `item` LIKE 'S%'
ORDER BY `item` ASC
```

and likely done in that order by the database backend.

As for operating on a normal data structure (such as a `List<T>`) I would agree with astander that they will be executed in left to right order.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: `WHERE`, then `ORDER BY`.

The more complex answer is: the LINQ query would be translated to an SQL query (going by your linq-to-sql tag), so it's a SQL server implementation detail. Usually it would run the `WHERE` clause first and then order the results (to save the cost of comparing results that don't even need to be returned), but I suppose it might do the ordering first if it's being ordered by a clustered index or something like that.